# Build a data warehouse and business intelligence using sql server 2014 from mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

As a beginner on data warehouse (DWH) and business intelligence (BI) world, I wonder how to build a DWH in SQL server 2014 (OLAP) from mysql (OLTP) and make it run automatically at a certain hour, and then it automatically creates a BI on the website's dashboard using that DWH? Is there any pdf guide or something that help me to develop this project?

Comment: StackOverflow is hardly the place for a Basic Course in Data Warehousing. You should study the field yourself and come back with more specific questions.

Comment: Do you have a recommendation website or video according my data warehouse question? @Juha K

Comment: Initially to start with building a DWH (OLAP) database, you need data from OLTP. For that, you can go with some ETL tools. There are many ETL tools available. Also for BI there are many BI tools available. I do not want to market any tools here. This is just a kick start for your question.

Comment: @Yoel try Ralph Kimball's books. You should understand though that building a Data Warehouse is an entire study field. It's like asking "I don't know programming, how can I build a 3D FPS?". Creating an SSIS package and running it every hour using a SQL Server agent job is the *easiest* part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to create SSIS ETL packages that will pull data from mySQL and load in your DWH; then create a job that runs the packages periodically.
Just like @Juka K said, you need to do a foundation course in SQL BI with focus on SSIS. There are many crash courses on edx.org, lynda.com and Google. Some of these are free and will give you some ideas on how/where to start.

Good luck!

Comment: Brilliant, I will try your suggestion.